# how to schedule a task that runs a command or script when a user logs on?

Tags: cron, at, anacron

I want to program a script that is launched whenever a specific user, let's call it `user` log in.

For example, when you log on to the computer with that user or using the `su` command on a terminal.

I can use any software such as crontab, anacron or at; or any other similar software.

preferably crontab, if you could:

```
? ? ? ? ? user /path/script.sh
```

Comment: this you want is a job of `.bash_profile` or .bashrc` files in the home directory of the user

Comment: Please see `man pam_access` to have better control of login process. You could run scripts, send an email when someone logs in and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, as @Romeo Ninov mentioned in a comment, I added the script to `.bashrc` from `user` so that it is executed each time it is logged in.